How to Prevent Coroutine Resource Leaks After Object Deletion in Kotlin?
I'm working with coroutines in Kotlin and encountered an issue where jobs continue to run even after the object that started them is set to null. This leads to resource leaks, with coroutines still executing and occupying memory even after the object is supposedly dead.
Here's a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the problem:
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

class SomeClass {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + CoroutineName("MyScope"))
    
    init {
        scope.launch {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(1000)  // Task runs every second
                val coroutineName = coroutineContext[CoroutineName]?.name ?: "Unknown"
                println("Executing periodic task in coroutine: $coroutineName")
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass2 {
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    
    val sharedFlow = flow {
        while (coroutineContext.isActive) {
            delay(1000)  // Task runs every second
            val coroutineName = coroutineContext[CoroutineName]?.name ?: "Unknown"
            println("Executing periodic task in coroutine: $coroutineName")
            emit("Executing periodic task...")
        }
    }.shareIn(scope + CoroutineName("MyScope"), started = SharingStarted.Eagerly, replay = 1)
}

fun main() {
    var someClass: SomeClass2? = SomeClass2()

    // Simulate the object working for a while
    Thread.sleep(3000)

    // Simulate the "death" of the object
    someClass = null

    // Program continues running
    Thread.sleep(5000)

    // Try to trigger garbage collection
    val dataList = mutableListOf<DataClass>()
    for (i in 1..100000000) {
        dataList.add(DataClass("OLOLOOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOO$i"))
    }

    println("Program continues running")
    println(dataList.size)

    // Program continues running
    Thread.sleep(5000)

    println("End of main")
}

data class DataClass(val a: String)

Output:
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Program continues running
100000000
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
Executing periodic task in coroutine: MyScope
End of main

Problem:
Even after setting someClass to null, the coroutines continue to execute, indicating a resource leak. I've also noticed that after creating a large number of objects (occupying around 12GB of memory), the coroutines still aren't terminated. This suggests that the garbage collector isn't reclaiming the memory, and the jobs are not being cancelled.
Question:
How can I properly handle the cancellation of coroutines in this scenario to avoid resource leaks? Is there a recommended pattern or approach in Kotlin to ensure that coroutines are terminated when the owning object is no longer in use?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
*Update
Thank you for the previous answers! I’ve understood that cancelling coroutines is the responsibility of the class or the user of that class. However, I have two additional questions related to scenarios where a CoroutineScope is injected using Dagger or used within a sharedFlow.

How do you correctly cancel coroutines when the CoroutineScope is injected, for example, via Dagger 2?
Dagger creates and provides objects but does not handle their destruction. If a CoroutineScope is injected via Dagger, how should one manage the lifecycle of the coroutines launched within that scope to ensure they are properly cancelled when the associated object is no longer needed?

Is it necessary to manually stop a sharedFlow?
In my example, I’m using a sharedFlow that launches coroutines internally. Is it correct to assume that I need to manually stop this flow to avoid resource leaks? If so, what are the best practices for doing this?


Any help or guidance on these questions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Associate objects with lifetimes with coroutine scopes, and properly close the scopes when done with the object.

If we create a CoroutineScope, we are responsible to cancel it when it is no longer needed. This is explained in the documentation for CoroutineScope function:

CoroutineScope should be declared as a property on entities with a well-defined lifecycle that are responsible for launching child coroutines. (...) The key part of custom usage of CoroutineScope is cancelling it at the end of the lifecycle. The CoroutineScope.cancel extension function shall be used when the entity that was launching coroutines is no longer needed. It cancels all the coroutines that might still be running on behalf of it.

To fix your example, we need to design a proper lifecycle for the SomeClass. The easiest is to create a function like: fun stop(): Unit = scope.cancel() and call it before someClass = null. It could be tempting to cancel the scope in the finalize method, however, this seems more like a hack and may still cause leaks.
In many cases, it is better to avoid creating custom coroutine scopes at all. Coroutines feature a structured concurrency concept, so by design they form a tree of related subtasks. If all coroutines are descendants of a single, root coroutine scope created in the main function, then cancelling all coroutines is a matter of simply cancelling that root scope. If we use CoroutineScope(), we "plant" new trees and we have to manage them manually.
Your example could be easily adapted to benefit from structured concurrency:
class SomeClass {
    suspend fun run() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default + CoroutineName("MyScope")) {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(1000)  // Task runs every second
                val coroutineName = coroutineContext[CoroutineName]?.name ?: "Unknown"
                println("Executing periodic task in coroutine: $coroutineName")
            }
        }
    }
}

Whoever needs the SomeClass or manages it, launches the run(). Then, if the consumer/manager is cancelled, SomeClass is automatically cancelled as well. Also, it makes much harder to accidentally leak background tasks, because the caller of our class is constantly waiting for it.

The garbage collector cleans up the memory of objects that are no longer externally referenced from anywhere (you used the phrase "dead objects"). But somewhere there must be a source/starting place from which the GC determines if things are referenced externally. This starting place is functions that have been started and haven't returned yet. Coroutines, just like Threads, are running functions, and so anything directly touched by a coroutine that has not completed has a reference held on it. It doesn't matter if there is no longer a reference to the coroutine Job, or the CoroutineScope that launched the Job.
If you have a class that has its own internal CoroutineScope, then it is your responsibility to cancel its scope before the reference to that class is dropped, or it will leak any active coroutines and anything those coroutines touch.
As for the design aspect for your app, if you have a class that needs its own CoroutineScope, you need to be careful how you use it. Whatever class instantiates it must be responsible for reporting to it when its about to be destroyed and so must cancel its own scope.

You should use ensureActive() in your CoroutineScope.
More information is here: docs

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
